# How can I properly set the "ballerina.home" path in VS Code? VS Code keeps saying it cannot detect ballerina

Tags: visual-studio-code, ballerina

I have ballerina installed but for some reason it is not detected in my VS Code environment.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both ballerina and the ballerina extensions in VS Code to no avail. What is the "ballerina.home" path on MacBook? I know how to configure it on windows but mac is giving me issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The `ballerina.home` path on macOS is the directory where you have installed Ballerina.
By default, on macOS, Ballerina gets installed in the `/Library/Ballerina/` directory if you install using the package file[1].
If you used Homebrew to install Ballerina, it's  `/usr/local/Cellar/ballerina/<BALLERINA-VERSION>/libexec` directory[2].

You can find `ballerina.home` path on your MacBook by running the below command on the terminal.

```
bal home
```

Ideally, Ballerina should be detected automatically on your VS Code environment. But, since you are facing an issue, please set the `ballerina.home` configuration and enable `ballerina.pluginDevMode` to use this[3].

1. https://ballerina.io/downloads/installation-options/#install-on-macos
2. https://ballerina.io/downloads/installation-options/#install-via-homebrew
3. https://wso2.com/ballerina/vscode/docs/configure-the-extension/